# IBM Heap Dump Analyzer | Out of memory

Tags: java, memory, heap-dump

I am running on 7 GM Ram machine , I have a heap dump file of size 1.8 GB . I am using Java 8 of 64 bit and running on 64 bit machine.
When i try to open the phd file from heap dump analyzer tool , it throws out of memory error. I am setting java vm args for heap analyzer tool as below
*java -Xmx4g -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit*
but still i am unable to open file. Please let me know how can i overcome this.

Comment: doing this: `java -Xmx4g -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit` will not set those parameters. If you really want to set them, you need to do that for the heap tool that you are using.

Comment: I am doing it for the tool , just updated the question

Comment: Also try to set the minimum heap size `java -Xms4g -Xmx4g -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit`.

Comment: Tried that no change

Answer (score 2):

This happens due to that the default heap size is smaller than needed by the dump size to be loaded, to resolve this, you need to set the VM args Xms, and XmX with the right values, below is what worked for me:

```
"<JAVA_PATH>\Java.exe" -Xms256m -Xmx6144m -jar <HEAP_ANALYSER_NAME>.jar
```

I hope that helps, I know it is a bit late response :)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue multiple times. I noticed that the analyzer runs better on Linux. On windows it needs a very large amount of memory most of the times - and surprisingly I did not see any apparent direct co-relation between the heapdump size and the required xmx size by the analyzer.

You can either try on Linux if that is an option, or increase the xmx size further.

Answer (score 0):

I Installed JDK 1.8 along with JRE 1.8 and made the changes Java Runtime Environment Settings : java control panel --> Java --> View --> User (Run Time Parameters to -Xms256m -Xmx6144m) and enable both JRE and JDK 1.8 versions.

This works out finally :) ; give it a try, JDK1.8 64bit in Windows.